# How to get back before a git stash -k followed by a git stash pop?

Tags: git

I was working on building a commit.

I wanted to make sure the subset of changes I had added still compiled before I commited them. So, I did `git stash -k` to stash all but the staged changes, went to compile, and found it worked.

Then, I popped what was left over back on via `git stash pop`

Now there's merge conflicts and it seemingly did some kind of a partial merge and nearly everything was `git add`'d without my consent. Not a few either. Hundreds of lines of complexity here across many files.

What the heck am I supposed to do? There shouldn't be any conflicts, I never committed, pulled, pushed, etc.

I just want to get back to either the state before `git stash -k` (ideally) or at the very least, what I had before I staged anything, just the loose edits. I can rebuilt the commit from the unstaged changes if I need to with some time.

Comment: No. I cannot lose the changes I made (so force or -f is not an option) and just un-doing the pop will not fix my problem - I need to get back before the ```stash -k```. If I just get back before the pop, I would eventually need to pop to get all my other changes, resulting in this awful conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To restore exactly what you stashed without regard to what's there now:

```
git read-tree --reset -u stash    # reset index and work tree to the stashed work tree
git read-tree stash^2             # reset the index to the stashed index
```

Whatever your test compile did apparently changed tracked files, and you weren't expecting/don't want those changes.

Comment: I cannot express my gratitude enough. Thank you for saving me from an awful git situation.